# HTML - Making two sets of text next to each other, in list format, equally

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to basically use html code to get text to appear like it is all lined up smoothly:

So it will be -

Client: Name

About: Name

(this can be seen at the bottom of my website page here: http://award46.com/motion/), its not the easiest thing to explain. I basically want to have it inline next to each other with equal amount of space between the client and name / about and name.

The following code being used for this is:

```
<p>THIS IS A TEST</p>
```

```
 .Inline dt, dd
    {

        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 30px;
        line-height: 14px;
        display:inline;              
    }


   .tm dt
    {

        padding-left: 20px;
        text-align: right;
        width: 100px;
    }
```

```
<div class="Inline">
  </dl>             
     <dt>Client: </dt>              
        <dd>Frank Faria / Metro Skateboarding</dd>
  </dl>
</div>

<div class="Inline">
  </dl>             
     <dt>Profile: </dt>              
        <dd>Personal</dd>
  </dl>
</div>

<div class="Inline">
  </dl>             
     <dt>About: </dt>              
        <dd>A small project based on making a smooth skateboarding video with a simple interpretation of phantom.</dd>
  </dl>
</div>

<div class="Inline">
  </dl>             
     <dt>Year: </dt>              
        <dd>July 2013</dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

Thank you for any responses in advance.

Kind regards,

Aaron

Comment: You initial `</dl>` selectors should be `<dl>blah</dl>`

Comment: Do you want the text in the `dt` tags to be aligned so that you have a ragged left (the :'s line up on the right) or have the labels left justified so taht the :'s form a ragged right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I understand now. On your site, it looks like the right side of the content of the list is not vertically aligned.

Currently they are mis-aligned like so:

[image]

You can solve this by adding this to your `dd` style selector:

```
dd {
   position: absolute;
   left: 30px; /* you can change this value to your preference */
}
```

With that style add it will look like this:

[image]

I tried this in Chrome's Inspector on your site and it worked fine.

As I stated above you should also clean up the `<dl>` tags because they are all currently `</dl>` and thus show syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler way of doing it using fewer tags.

You can keep your 4 lines in a single list:

```
<dl> 
    <dt>Client: </dt> 
    <dd>Frank Faria / Metro Skateboarding</dd> 
    <dt>Profile: </dt> 
    <dd>Personal</dd> 
    <dt>About: </dt> 
    <dd>A small project based on making a smooth skateboarding 
        video with a simple interpretation of phantom.</dd> 
    <dt>Year: </dt> 
    <dd>July 2013</dd>
</dl>
```

Apply the following CSS:

```css
dl {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: auto;
}
dt {
    border: 1px dotted gray;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    margin: 0;
    width: 5em;
}
dd { 
    border: 1px dotted blue; 
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/5RsES/

The trick is to float the `dt` elements to the left and assign them a fixed width.
(You can text-align left/right as you see fit.)

You can then use `overflow: auto` on the `dd` to keep the text in a nice block if it were long enough to wrap into a second or third line.

Finally, apply `overflow: auto` to the parent `dl` element to keep the floats nicely bundled together without affecting any other text elements outside of the parent block.